# how to install Ubuntu Server with GPT GUID Partition Table

Tags: partitioning

How do you install Ubuntu server on an empty 4TB hard drive using GPT GUID Partition Table?

I came from FreeBSD and in the FreeBSD installation, you can select the Partition Scheme (APM, BSD, GPT, MBR, PC98, etc.) for the volume.   There is no such option in the Ubuntu Server installation (from CD).

Also, I read somewhere that even if the machine has the old style BIOS and not the newer UEFI, Linux can still use GPT and thus accept more than 2.2GB partition.   Is this correct?

Thank you very much in anticipation.

ZMWei

Answer (score 0):

The installer will use GPT automatically for disks over 2 TiB.  As long as you choose one of the automatic options everything will work automatically.  If you wish to choose the manual partitioning option, you just need to make sure to create a 1 MiB bios_grub partition if your machine is bios booting instead of uefi.

Comment: Thank you psusi for the answer.   What if we are installing Ubuntu Server on a old machine which is BIOS-based and not UEFI ?  Do we also just need to create a 1MB bios_grub partition if we are using manual partitioning?    And if we choose Auto, Ubuntu installer will automatically use GPT for disk over 2TB even if the machine is not UEFI?

Comment: @ZMWei, correct.  The auto option will create either the bios_grub or efi system partition depending on whether the machine supports uefi or not.